# Can't run docker container in different user

Tags: docker, ubuntu, firefox

I have 2 users on my ubuntu: personal and work. I created a docker image to run firefox in a container. To make things simple I added an alias in my .bash_aliases file to run it by typing "firefox" in terminal like so:

```
docker run --rm -d --name firefox \
-v $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/pulse:$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/pulse \
-e PULSE_SERVER=$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/pulse/native \
-v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix \
-e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY \
--network host \
shallowduck/firefox:1.0
```

The problem is that firefox does not launch when I'm logged in as "work" user, only "personal".

- When I run the command I get container id as output in terminal but nothing launches.
- When I run docker ps, the container isn't there.
- When I run docker ps -a, there is no trace that the container exited with an error or whatever.
- Both users are part of the docker group.

I'm not sure what I'm missing. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you getting an X error?

Comment: @stdunbar I had to run this: xhost +. Now that I did, it works perfectly. :)

Comment: That's what I expected.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fixed this by running this command in terminal:

```
xhost +
```

This adds host names on the list of machines that can connect to X server. I forgot I had to run this command for each user.

Comment: This enables anyone who can connect to your X server to run a screen capture or keyboard logger.

Comment: Then what should I do?